# Retain one column in a data frame as POSIXct and convert others to numeric in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data-transform

Leaving the date column I would like to convert rest of the columns in a data frame from chr to numeric. How could I achieve this? There are many columns in the data frame and below is only an extract. Thanks.

```
                 Date RECORD Battery_V Data_logger_Temp_C VWC_CS7
  2021-06-25 12:34:00      0     12.47              14.14   0.127
```

Comment: What have tried so far?  Do you know about `colnames(df)` and for example `for (col in colnames(df)) { # do something here  ... }`  ?

Comment: I tried a bit on sapply but it didn't gave the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the data frame shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  Then  convert all columns except the first as shown. No packages are used.

```
DF2 <- replace(DF, -1, lapply(DF[-1], as.numeric))
```

or

```
DF2 <- DF
DF2[-1] <- lapply(DF2[-1], as.numeric)
```

or we can convert all character columns using:

```
ok <- sapply(DF, is.character)
DF2 <- replace(DF, ok, lapply(DF[ok], as.numeric))
```

or

```
DF2 <- DF
ok <- sapply(DF2, is.character)
DF2[ok] <- lapply(DF2[ok], as.numeric)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "                 Date RECORD Battery_V Data_logger_Temp_C VWC_CS7
  2021-06-25T12:34:00      0     12.47              14.14   0.127"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, colClasses = "character",
  strip.white = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.POSIXct(DF$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = -Date, as.numeric))
```

Comment: Thanks though couldn't test this.